# Xamarin.forms - How to display tabs on the middle of a layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to add tabs just below custom header(Grid), but I am not sure how to do that. So far I have grid and tabbedPage, but how to display both in one page? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not possible with Xamarin.Forms - at least not out of the box, of course you can write custom renderers for something like a TabView.

Note that with X.F you are limited to very basic UIs.